# apache2.conf errors

Tags: apache, apache2

The actual directory of the apache2.conf is /etc/apache/apache.conf.  And there is sites-enabled directory.  I changed the directory path of the sites-enabled directory to /var/www/sites-enabled.  Further went on to change the directory pat of the sites-enabled in the apacche2.conf as ../../var/www/sites-enabled/

It throws the error

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/var/www/sites-enabled/: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Any ideas on how I could resolve this?

Put in the correct path now it throws this error

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /var/www/sites-enabled/000-default: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

You might have built the dangling a while ago. You should remove the association by

`d2dissite 000-default`

Then add your website alias with

`a2ensite yoursite.com`

Answer (score 0):

I met similar errors before. It occurred when I was  installing new modules but configured it wrongly. My solution was to locate the error configuration and remove the configure file.

If the error was caused by modules related configuration, you can try:

`/etc/init.d/apache2 -M`

This generated error message for me

`apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ example.load: No such file or directory`

I checked that directory, and found there is an `example.load` file, I deleted it and restart the server, and the problem solved.

Generally, I think you should try:

1. locate which was the origin of the error. 

   `systemctl status apach2.status`
2. If it is originated by wrong module configurations, locate which configuration file was the origin of the error.

   `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

In your case, it may be caused by your wrong configuration on the site, you can check the configuration and modify it correctly.

Answer (score -3):

It was due to permission error
sudo apache2 restart